# Subset and group dataframe by matching columns and values R

Tags: r, dataframe, grouping, subset

I have 2 dataframes, df1 contains a groupID and continuous variables like so:

```
GroupID      Var1      Var2         Var3      Var4
1          20.33115  19.59319    0.6384765  0.6772862
1          31.05899  23.14446    0.5796645  0.7273182
2          24.28984  20.99047    0.6425050  0.6865804
2          22.47856  21.36709    0.6690020  0.6368560
3          21.65817  20.99444    0.6829786  0.6461840
3          23.45899  21.57718    0.6655482  0.6473043
```

And df2 contains cutoff values (ct) for each variable:

```
Var1ct    Var2ct    Var3ct    Var4ct
22.7811   20.3349   0.7793    0.4294
```

What I want to do is, for each variable in df1, find the number of rows where the value is greater than the cutoff value in its associated columnn in df2 and return that number for each groupID, so the output would look like this:

```
GroupID   N-Var1   N-Var2   N-Var3   N-Var4
1          62       78       33       99
2          69       25       77       12
3          55       45       27       62
```

df1 is ~ 2million rows unevenly distributed by GroupID and 30 variable columns I need the count for, I am just looking for a more effecient way than typing out the same function for all 30 variables.

Comment: When asking people to code for you it is mostly always a good idea to give the data in terms of R code so people can easily try something out. If everything else fails, try a `for`-loop over the numbers `i in 2:ncol(df1)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way in `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(GroupID) %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), ~ sum(.x > df2[grepl(cur_column(), colnames(df2))][, 1])))

  GroupID  Var1  Var2  Var3  Var4
    <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1       1     1     1     0     2
2       2     1     2     0     2
3       3     1     2     0     2
```

---

data

```r
df1 <- read.table(header = T, text = "GroupID      Var1      Var2         Var3      Var4
1          20.33115  19.59319    0.6384765  0.6772862
1          31.05899  23.14446    0.5796645  0.7273182
2          24.28984  20.99047    0.6425050  0.6865804
2          22.47856  21.36709    0.6690020  0.6368560
3          21.65817  20.99444    0.6829786  0.6461840
3          23.45899  21.57718    0.6655482  0.6473043 ")

df2 <- read.table(header = T, text = "Var1ct    Var2ct    Var3ct    Var4ct
22.7811   20.3349   0.7793    0.4294")
```

Comment: I don't think you need a `rowwise()` approach: `df1 %>% group_by(GroupID) %>% summarise(across(everything(), ~sum(.x > df2[grepl(cur_column(), colnames(df2))])))` should do the trick. :-)

Comment: It seems it gives different results unfortunately. But I agree it might be possible to avoid the `rowwise` approach.

Comment: Got it! Just had to add [, 1].

Answer (score 4):

a data.table approach that should scale well..

```
library(data.table)
# if df1 and dsf2 are not data.table, use
# setDT(df)1; setDT(df2)

# we need similara columnnames in df1 and df2 to easily join
setnames(df2, names(df1)[2:5])

# melt df1 and  to long format
df1.long <- melt(df1, id.vars = "GroupID")
df2.long <- melt(df2, measure.vars = names(df2))

# join ct-values
df1.long[df2.long, ct := i.value, on = .(variable)]

# summarise
ans <- df1.long[, sum(value > ct), by = .(GroupID, variable)]

# cast to wide
dcast(ans, GroupID ~ variable, value.var = "V1")
#    GroupID Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4
# 1:       1    1    1    0    2
# 2:       2    1    2    0    2
# 3:       3    1    2    0    2
```

**sample data**

```
df1 <- fread("GroupID      Var1      Var2         Var3      Var4
1          20.33115  19.59319    0.6384765  0.6772862
1          31.05899  23.14446    0.5796645  0.7273182
2          24.28984  20.99047    0.6425050  0.6865804
2          22.47856  21.36709    0.6690020  0.6368560
3          21.65817  20.99444    0.6829786  0.6461840
3          23.45899  21.57718    0.6655482  0.6473043 ")

df2 <- fread("Var1ct    Var2ct    Var3ct    Var4ct
22.7811   20.3349   0.7793    0.4294")
```